# BigQuery UDF: DECLARE/SET variable inside Standard SQL UDF body

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

NOTE: This may be considered a duplicate of [How to declare variable inside BigQuery UDF body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63147752/how-to-declare-variable-inside-bigquery-udf-body), but I am not satisfied with the answers provided - None answer how to DECLARE/SET variables within the UDF, and the language documentation [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language), [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) does not discuss this either.

Given the following JS UDF:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION earliest_full_payment(
    payments ARRAY<STRUCT<event_key STRING, amount FLOAT64, td_amount FLOAT64, date DATE>>,
    td_charges_amount FLOAT64
)
RETURNS STRUCT<event_key STRING, amount FLOAT64, td_amount FLOAT64, date DATE>
LANGUAGE js
AS
r"""
    let result = null;
    for(const payment of payments) {
        const payment_amount = (payment.amount || 0)
        const td_payment_amount = (payment.td_amount || 0)
        if (payment_amount < 0) {
            if (td_payment_amount < td_charges_amount) {
                result = null;
            }
        } else {
            if (td_payment_amount >= td_charges_amount) {
                result = payment
            }
        }
    }
return result
""";
```

I am trying to produce the equivalent Standard SQL UDF:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION earliest_full_payment(
    payments ARRAY<STRUCT<event_key STRING, amount FLOAT64, td_amount FLOAT64, date DATE>>,
    td_charges_amount FLOAT64
)
RETURNS STRUCT<event_key STRING, amount FLOAT64, td_amount FLOAT64, date DATE>
AS
((
    DECLARE result STRUCT<event_key STRING, amount FLOAT64, td_amount FLOAT64, date DATE>;
    SET result = NULL;
    FOR payment IN UNNEST(payments) DO
        DECLARE payment_amount FLOAT64;
        DECLARE td_payment_amount FLOAT64;
        SET payment_amount = IFNULL(payment.amount, 0);
        SET td_payment_amount = IFNULL(payment.td_amount, 0);
        IF payment_amount < 0 THEN
            IF td_payment_amount < td_charges_amount THEN
              SET result = NULL;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            IF td_payment_amount >= td_charges_amount THEN
                SET result = payment
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END FOR;
    RETURN result;
));
```

but I get `Syntax error: Unexpected identifier "result" at [8:13]`.
I tried both with the DECLARE inside and outside of the UDF, and with a BEGIN..END around the statements.

Any idea how I can fix the syntax error?

Comment: You'd better consider a stored procedure rather than an UDF since you can't use multiple statements in an UDF.

Comment: Oh! That's a great insight :D Thanks @Jaytiger.  I converted the SQL UDF to a stored procedure, but I get a syntax error "Syntax error: Expected ")" but got "." at [5:25]" when trying to run it. Here's the gist - https://gist.github.com/philippefutureboy/2b5dd90c25a9697499b5cd0517f23b5e - Any idea what may be the issue?

Comment: You can't use `CALL` statement in *select* list like in your test case since it's not an expression.

Comment: Can you confirm whether the answer below solved your issue or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood your logic in UDFs, but seems you can implement it with an UDF in SQL-lish way like below.

- Below UDF has passed all TCs you defined

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION earliest_full_payment(
  payments ARRAY<STRUCT<event_key STRING, amount FLOAT64, td_amount FLOAT64, date DATE>>,
  td_charges_amount FLOAT64
) AS ((
  SELECT CASE
           WHEN IFNULL(p.amount, 0) >= 0 AND IFNULL(p.td_amount, 0) >= td_charges_amount THEN p
           WHEN IFNULL(p.amount, 0) < 0 AND IFNULL(p.td_amount, 0) < td_charges_amount THEN null
         END
   FROM UNNEST(payments) p WITH offset
  ORDER BY offset DESC LIMIT 1
));
```

Comment: Seems like an equivalent way to go about it. This works! While this solves my use case, it doesn't answer the question - how to DECLARE/SET variables in a UDF; If you can come up with an answer that use a procedure as you suggested, and that has DECLARE/SET statements, I'll accept that answer. Cheers!

Comment: for your question `how to DECLARE/SET variables in a UDF;`, answer is it's not possible. `DECLARE` and `SET` is a statement and it's not allowed to use multiple statements in an UDF.   And for the procedure you defined, I think it works nicely. Only problem is you can 't put the procedure where an *expression* is expected as you did in your test cases since a procedure is a statement.

Comment: Is it possible to call/execute the procedure as part of an expression - at all?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Alright! Then I accepted your answer. Cheers!